# How to send nft to another account in scrypto?

Tags: scrypto

So I have two nft's in my account:

```
{ amount: 2, resource address: resource_sim1qfms4etzwnhsdpj5ys9shy9jgv2yp0z9w6ud8z9fyv7svqnjty, ", name: \"mutablenft\""", symbol: \"MNFT\"" }
   ├─ NonFungible { id: NonFungibleLocalId("#0#"), data: Tuple(Enum(0u8), Enum(0u8), 1u8) }
   └─ NonFungible { id: NonFungibleLocalId("#1#"), data: Tuple(Enum(0u8), Enum(0u8), 1u8) }
```

I want to send one of the nft's to another account. How do I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have another account created already, and the default account is now the one that holds the NFTs, try:

`resim transfer <resource_address>:<amount_or_comma_separated_nf_ids> <recipient_address>`